# wamp server - access denied when navigating localhost/phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp

When trying to reach `localhost/phpmyadmin` in WAMP, I get the following error:

> Error: #1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Please tell me if I need to reset my password, or how to get it?

Answer (score 1):

The MySQL manual explains how to [reset permissions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/resetting-permissions.html), but the MySQL defaults are username root with a blank password. I don't know if WAMP might have set an alternative default password instead.